# How to scroll smoothly ScrollViewer in Windows 8 Metro App?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml

I have such question: I have a ScrollViewer in my XAML/C# app for windows 8. Inside the ScrollViewer there is a Grid with dinamic count of Columns, I set ColumnDefenitions in code when program is loaded. But when I tryed to Scroll this grid in ScrollViewer with

```
scrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(myOffset);
```

It scroll instantly, but I want it to scroll while some time, smoothly. Help me plz how can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried different Offsets? What is the value of `myOffset`? How many columns do you have? What does **dinamic** mean exactly?

Comment: I have some of data, and it is devided to different parts. Every this part must be shown in different columns. Data is loaded from server, and its count may be differ from 1 to N, Width of every column is constant, for scroling I use offset equals _index * _columnWidth and it  allows me to scroll to column with index == _columnIndex. I use code I write at my question, it scrolls correctly, but it happens instantly, without animation. But I want it ti be animated.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved using `Storyboard`, see following example (which can be also applied even to Windows Phone 8):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/08/04/scrolling-so-smooth-like-the-butter-on-a-muffin-how-to-animate-the-horizontal-verticaloffset-properties-of-a-scrollviewer.aspx

**Edit:**

New link: http://dlaa.me/blog/post/9857745 ([backup](https://web.archive.org/web/20160408030156/http://dlaa.me/blog/post/9857745))